# Character modeling: character's front view appear at side view port in Blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

[image: Right hand side is front view port, left hand side is side view port]

I am new to Blender. I think i accidently click something and my model become like this. The character's front view appear at side view port and character's side view appear at front view port. What should i do in order to change everything back to normal? i mean turn character's front view back to front view port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotate your object to make it fit the viewport - select it, press **R** to start rotating, right after that press **Z** to limit rotation to Z axis, next type in **90** on your keyboard to make it rotate 90 degree along Z axis.

Try it out, it might be I am giving you wrong degrees out of my head, just experiment, it should be fairly easy to figure out.

After that you might consider applying your rotation to the object (so it thinks that's its default rotation he is in right now) by pressing **ctrl+A** and selecting **rotation**.

You can also press **N** hotkey when having mouse cursor centered on 3d view - this way you will be able to see rotations, translations and scale under Transforms panel, and change them however you like.

Comment: Hi, It works! But after i save the project and turn it off. Reopen the same project, the model change back to the same pose.

Comment: Is it because the position of the cursor? but i have set it to geometry...

Comment: I found the problem. I accidentally set a keyframe. Thank you very much!!